# Circular dependencies that cannot be fulfilled. PHP packages on CentOS 7 to support Drupal 8

Tags: centos, rpm, php, apache-httpd, drupal

I am trying to install Drupal 8.0.5 on Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7, with PHP 5.6.19.  I get an error that PHP extensions are disabled.  The detail I get is that it pertains to "gd."

I have installed, with yum install these packages: gd, gd-devel, php-gd, php-pdo php-mbstring, php-xml.

I have installed various other packages.  I have no reason to think that PHP gd extensions have not been enabled.  They've certainly been installed.  I've restarted Apache services and MariaDB services. I've rebooted the sever.

I reinstalled Drupal and PHP.  I created a php.ini file with "extension=gd.so" as the content.

What should I do to get Drupal working for the first time?  I have never done this before.  How do I enable the PHP Extensions?  Or is the message false?  If it is, what should I do?

Main problem (circular dependencies that can never be fulfilled):
To ensure that I have the correct versions of the packages, I tried to install php56-php-common-5.6.19-2.fc24.remi.x86_64.rpm.  But I get an error that it requires php56-php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64).  To handle this requirement, I tried to install this package.  I then tried to install php56-php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.  But I got an error that I needed php56-php(zend-abi).  This package seems to be the php56-php-common one above.  When I search for php56-php(zend-abi), I get brought to this URL: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php56-php%28zend-abi%29

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

All this package comes from this SCL: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php56/ You need to enable this repo. Then you need to operate with SCL similarly as this tutorial  http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2013/08/01/php-5-4-on-rhel-6-using-rhscl/ (just replace php54 with php56).